# Copy the current line to end of buffer without moving cursor?

Tags: vim

I know I can do this:

```
:.co$
```

But this also moves the cursor to the end, how can I prevent the 
cursor from moving in this case?

Comment: Do you accept if the cursor move in processing but will be back to your current position after finishing yank?

Comment: Yeah, if absolutely staying where it was is not possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, here, is that `:copy` (like most if not all line-oriented Ex commands) *always* moves the cursor to the target. There's no flag or option or whatever at your disposal to change that behavior.

But it's easy to go back to where you come from so… why bother?

```
:k'|t$
''
```

or, in normal mode:

```
yyGp<C-o>
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode, place the cursor at the line where you want to start copy, then type:

```
vG$y
```

- `v` switch you to visual mode
- `G` select all to begin of last line
- `$` select to the end of last line
- `y` yank all selected line

after that, you cursor will move back to where it began.